# Google Cloud SQL - "SELECT .. AS .." doesn't change the column name

Tags: sql, select, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to retrieve some columns value from a google cloud sql database, and I want to rename the output column as follows:

```
select id as tot from mytable
```

the query result I get is this:

```
  id
value1
value2
value3
...
```

as you can see the column name is not changed as I wanted.. I also tried

```
select id as 'tot' from mytable
```

and (in fact this works, but obviously every row value is set to 'id' instead of the real row value)

```
select 'id' as 'tot' from mytable
```

the table schema I'm testing on is as simple as possible:

```
create table mytable(id varchar(10))
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help, best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as expected using the command line tool and looks like a bug in the web ui.

Here's what I got from the command line tool use (google_sql.sh)

```
sql> insert into mytable values('1'), ('2'), ('3');
3 row(s) affected.
sql> select * from mytable;                        
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.10 sec)

sql> select id as 'tot' from mytable
-> ;
+-----+
| tot |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.09 sec)

sql> select 'id' as 'tot' from mytable
-> ;
+-----+
| tot |
+-----+
| id  |
| id  |
| id  |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

I just logged a bug for this: https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=60